# StackOverflowError Jackson with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, stack-overflow

I have a Spring Boot Project with Jackson.

Whenever I start it, I get this exception (production environment only).

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/apps/upiswitchv2/lib/upiswitchv2.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/apps/upiswitchv2/lib/upiswitchv2.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/apps/upiswitchv2/lib/upiswitchv2.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
2018-06-20 19:53:06,102 Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@773cbf4f]-1 ERROR com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.lang.reflect.Parameter["declaringExecutable"]->java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter["declaringExecutable"]->java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter["declaringExecutable"]-

java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter["declaringExecutable"]->java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter["declaringExecutable"]->java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"]->java.lang.reflect.Parameter["declaringExecutable"]->java.lang.reflect.Method["parameters"])

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:706)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:256)
at com.fa.....................

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:709)
    ... 1011 more
```

**Configuration**

```
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.7.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <jackson.version>2.8.5</jackson.version>
```

I have also provided a `customMessageConverter`

```
@Bean public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter =
        new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}
```

I also added Log4J Disruptor Jar and added property:

```
System.setProperty("log4j2.contextSelector", "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector");
```

Another observation: `StackOverflowErrors` increase whenever I get `MethodArgumentNotValidException`

For Example if I am using `@Pattern` Annotation, and if validation fails, `@RestControllerAdvice` catches `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, and in a short period of time (100ms) I get a `StackOverflowError` in SYSOUT.

Comment: Please explain your question, Because above code work for me fine.

Comment: Code works fine for me too, on local environment. However, I get this issue on production. I am looking for hints to debug this issue. Ill keep posting whatever I tried here.

Comment: have check log generated on server?

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you are serializing a class with properties of `parameters` and `declaringExecutable`. And in this case `parameters` contains a reference to `declaringExecutable` and in turn `declaringExecutable` has a reference back to `parameters`. This results in an infinite loop as the class gets serialized to JSON.

Take a look at removing the reference in one spot or the other. Or mark one side of the chain as a `@JsonIgnore`

Based on the comment:

The java.lang.reflect is just for the code that is trying to do the serialization. If you don't have anything with `declaringExecutable` and `parameters` there must be some of your code that is attempting to serialize a library class with those properties. Take a look at the return types on your endpoints and see if you're returning anything from a library that has that circular dependency.

Or post your controller class and any other serialization specific code in the question.

Comment: But those are java classes, not classes of my package

Comment: Updated notes in the answer

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more  :- how to "see if you're returning anything from a library that has that circular dependency." Also, the exception comes up at server startup while loading a class, how do i narrow down suspects. Can I turn on some logs which might help me in debugging this issue.

Comment: Might be tough to solve with logging given that it occurs at startup but i would for sure add log calls to any of the controller methods where you expect the end result to be JSON. Also check anything you're serializing to JSON as part of your startup process. Post your Controller class here for more details

Comment: I have a few things to share, will also soon share detailed version in the question after verifying: 

1) There is a custom converter in code which consumes form/url-encoded requests and automatically converts them to JSON.

2) There is only 1 Api which consumes = "application/json" (rest all are consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), and it is the one which when fails in validation , sometimes I see a stackOverflow error

3) Point 2 is just a theory, which can be wrong, need to verify it , which I will be doing soon and posting results here

Comment: Could be looking for produces more than consumes though it could be either depending on the startup flow. Sounds like you may have found the API. What kind of args does the consumes ="application/json" take?

Comment: No luck, All theories failed. And the error stopped coming, still trying to figure out what happened.

Comment: JsonIgnore worked for me. Got a similar stack overflow exception because I returned an EntityObject where and EntityObject refers to the first one.